# how to reschedule failed/error pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster with autoscale enabled and I am deploying pods dynamically when needed (not stateful), some pods are failing because node is running out of memory (expected). When it happens pod enters `status: Failed`, `reason: Evicted`, `Message: node was low on resource` even when new nodes can be spawned.

Is there is way to reschedule/retry this pod on different/new node automatically ?
if not, how can I re-deploy same pod without changing any config of it ?

Comment: Please clarify: are you talking about the pod autoscaler or the node autoscaler?

Comment: @BlenderFox node autoscaler

Comment: @ray Have you checked the node autoscaling, if that is working fine?

Comment: @karan525 yes it works perfectly but again it fails to move/retry evicted pod.

Comment: In this case, can you try increasing the size of the node in the node pool? A single node might node be capable of handling the resources requested by your pods. Also, try increasing the resources requested by your pod (your application might require more resources than what you have requested).

Comment: @karan525 if you meant no of nodes, yes I had 1 node initially, as I deployed more and more pods, at end I had 4 nodes running but still few pods failed and Ill give a try on increasing resource size.